# PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential() seems to be broken using firebaseAuth / Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement phone authentication in flutter using Firebase auth.
My environment is set up with the following:

- Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.5
- firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5

When I try to call this code (just hard-coding a verificationid):

```
        AuthCredential authCredential =  PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
          verificationId: '55', smsCode: smsCode);
```

nothing happens. I am expecting an error code when passing in invalid validation/smscode, but it just returns an empty instance of authCredential, which I can't do anything with?

Is this a bug or does someone else have this working with the above environment?
I need a way of verifying the authCredential returned is correct and valid.

Answer (score 0):

turns out, in order to get any real message, you need to provide a valid validationID.